# Adding kickstand to mt-100 iron horse bike

Tags: kickstand

It seems that my bike has a tube where I would expect to mount a kickstand. This tube has a horizontal hole in it. Do I need some special kickstand?

[image: picture of my bike]

Comment: Aside - that short tube is the chainstay bridge, and the hole is there during welding as a vent for hot gasses.  After assembly, the hole is for mounting a full-length fender/chainstay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several types of kickstand you can install.
Here are just two options.
A style similar to the one you have in mind will mount in front of the tube you mention.

[image]

There are also styles that will attach to the chain stay and seat stay - if you don't have a disk brake.
[image]